# Firestore limit / limitToLast snapshot issue with chat messages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a chat application in React Native that uses Firestore. When loading the Chat screen i get the latest messages by ordering by timeSent and limitToLast 25 items (to only load a small amount of items initially):

```
firestore
  .collection('group')
  .doc(group.id)
  .collection('messages')
  .orderBy('timeSent', 'asc')
  .limitToLast(25)
  .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
     // update state here
  })
```

The problem with this is that, if the message count is greater than the limit, the snapshot either:

1. Removes the last item when an item when a new item is added `change.type = 'removed'`
2. Retrieves limit - 1 item when an item when item is removed `change.type = 'added'`

limit and limitToLast do this by default.  I'm not sure how to stop it.  It's impossible to tell if a user deleted a chat message, or if the limit removed it because a new item got added, and vice versa.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?  I want to limit the items so the initial load is low and I also want to listen to changes to update the UI when new messages come in / get removed (by the user, not by the snapshot listener).

Surely there's a way to do this... Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is the expected, intended behavior of limit queries. The `.limitToLast(25)` clause on your query tells Firestore to give you a view of the last 25 documents, so if a new document occurs into that view another (the previous most "recent" in the view) document is removed.

If you want to show when a message gets deleted, the common approach is to implement a soft-delete. So don't really delete the document, but rather put a marker on the document to indicate that the message in it has been deleted. Not only does that mean it'll still show up in the results of the limit query, but it also means you can retain the history of the message.

If needed, you can then periodically run a process that actually deletes the documents for the soft-deleted messages, either by code you write yourself, or by [implementing a TTL policy](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/ttl).

Comment: That's exactly what i'm looking for!  I was hoping to actually delete the item so it's not increasing the read count for no reason, but if it's not possible then soft-deleting is a good alternative!  Thank you!